# This OpenMP code crashes linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, openmp

I was working on some code to row reduce a matrix using openmp.  I have two version of it and both make my Ubuntu and Fedora installations crash hard.  By hard I mean my mouse and keyboard are unresponsive, and even when I hit the reset button on my PC tower it will not restart.  I have to hold down the power button.  What is strange about this is that the code crashes after a few minutes of running.  It is not consuming large amounts of memory (I consider 750 mb to be small since I have 16gb of ram).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    public:

    Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols):
        data(0), w(rows), h(cols)
    {
        data = new double[w * h];
        memset(data, 0, sizeof(double) * w * h);
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        if(data)
        {
            delete[] data;
            w = h = 0;
            data = 0;
        }
    }

    double* operator[](size_t row)
    {
        return data + row * w;
    }

    const double* operator[](size_t row) const
    {
        return data + row * w;
    }

    size_t width() const
    {
        return w;
    }

    size_t height() const
    {
        return h;
    }

    void scale_row(size_t row, double x)
    {
        double* prow = (*this)[row];

        for(size_t i = 0; i < w; i++)
            prow[i] *= x;
    }

    void add_row(size_t dest_row, size_t source_row, double scaling = 1.0)
    {
        if(dest_row == source_row)
        {
            scale_row(dest_row, 1.0 + scaling);
            return;
        }

        double* __restrict__ drow = (*this)[dest_row];
        double* __restrict__ srow = (*this)[source_row];

        for(size_t i = 0; i < w; i++)
            drow[i] += srow[i] * scaling;
    }

    void swap_rows(size_t r1, size_t r2)
    {
        if(r1 == r2)
            return;

        double* __restrict__ a = (*this)[r1];
        double* __restrict__ b = (*this)[r2];

        #pragma omp parallel for simd
        for(size_t i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            double tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = b[i];
            b[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    double* find_leading(size_t row)
    {
        double* ptr = (*this)[row];
        for(size_t i = 0; i < w; i++)
            if(ptr[i])
                return ptr + i;
        return 0;
    }

    void clamp_zeros(double threshold = 1e-12)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for simd
        for(size_t i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
        {
            if(fabs(data[i]) < threshold)
                data[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    void row_reduce(Matrix* mirror = 0)
    {
        for(size_t r1 = 0; r1 < h; r1++)
        {
            double* lead = find_leading(r1);
            if(!lead)
                continue;

            size_t rank = lead - (*this)[r1];
            if(mirror)
                mirror->scale_row(r1, 1.0 / *lead);
            scale_row(r1, 1.0 / *lead);

            #pragma omp parallel for
            for(size_t r2 = 0; r2 < h; r2++)
            {
                if(r2 == r1 || (*this)[r2][rank] == 0)
                    continue;
                if(mirror)
                    mirror->add_row(r2, r1, -(*this)[r2][rank]);
                add_row(r2, r1, -(*this)[r2][rank]);
            }
            clamp_zeros();
        }

        size_t zero_count = 0;
        for(size_t r = 0; r < h; r++)
        {
            double* lead = find_leading(r);
            if(lead)
            {
                size_t rank = lead - (*this)[r];
                swap_rows(rank, r);
                if(mirror)
                    mirror->swap_rows(rank, r);
            }
            else
            {
                size_t with = h - ++zero_count;
                swap_rows(r, with);
                if(mirror)
                    mirror->swap_rows(r, with);
            }
        }
    }

    private:

    double* data;
    size_t w, h;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Matrix& m)
{
    o << setprecision(2);
    for(size_t j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
    {
        o << "----------";
    }
    o << "--\n";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m.height(); i++)
    {
        o << "|";
        for(size_t j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
        {
            o << setw(10) << m[i][j];
        }
        o << "|\n";
    }
    for(size_t j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
    {
        o << "----------";
    }
    o << "--";
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Matrix m (10000, 10000);

    for(int i = 0; i < m.height(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    time_t start = time(0);
    m.row_reduce();
    time_t end = time(0);
    cout << m[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "dt = " << (end - start) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried out another kind of stupid simple omp program to see if it would crash my system and this one did not.

```
double sum = 0.0;

double start = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for(long long i = 1; i < 100000000000000LL; i++)
{
    sum += 1.0 / ((double)i * i);
}
printf("%lf %lf\n", omp_get_wtime() - start, sum);
```

I tried the first one and ran into the same issue when I ran it on Ubuntu 15.04 compiled with gcc 4.9 and Fedora 22 compiled with gcc 5.1.

When I run it without openmp it works fine.  Also if I try smaller data like a 2000x2000 matrix it works fine (the crash happens when I try a 10,000x10,000 matrix).

Seems to work fine on my laptop which is also running ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some code alteration to support compatibility with OpenMP 2.0, and I can tell you, that your code runing well (Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008). Memory consumption about 800MB.

Output:

0

dt = 2881

Here is your altered code.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// OpenMP test function
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    public:

    Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols):
        data(0), w(rows), h(cols)
    {
        data = new double[w * h];
        memset(data, 0, sizeof(double) * w * h);
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        if(data)
        {
            delete[] data;
            w = h = 0;
            data = 0;
        }
    }

    double* operator[](size_t row)
    {
        return data + row * w;
    }

    const double* operator[](size_t row) const
    {
        return data + row * w;
    }

    size_t width() const
    {
        return w;
    }

    size_t height() const
    {
        return h;
    }

    void scale_row(size_t row, double x)
    {
        double* prow = (*this)[row];

        for(size_t i = 0; i < w; i++)
            prow[i] *= x;
    }

    void add_row(size_t dest_row, size_t source_row, double scaling = 1.0)
    {
        if(dest_row == source_row)
        {
            scale_row(dest_row, 1.0 + scaling);
            return;
        }

        double*  drow = (*this)[dest_row];
        double*  srow = (*this)[source_row];

        for(size_t i = 0; i < w; i++)
            drow[i] += srow[i] * scaling;
    }

    void swap_rows(size_t r1, size_t r2)
    {
        if(r1 == r2)
            return;

        double*  a = (*this)[r1];
        double*  b = (*this)[r2];

        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
        for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            double tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = b[i];
            b[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    double* find_leading(size_t row)
    {
        double* ptr = (*this)[row];
        for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            if(ptr[i])
                return ptr + i;
        return 0;
    }

    void clamp_zeros(double threshold = 1e-12)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
        for(int i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
        {
            if(fabs(data[i]) < threshold)
                data[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    void row_reduce(Matrix* mirror = 0)
    {
        for(size_t r1 = 0; r1 < h; r1++)
        {
            double* lead = find_leading(r1);
            if(!lead)
                continue;

            size_t rank = lead - (*this)[r1];
            if(mirror)
                mirror->scale_row(r1, 1.0 / *lead);
            scale_row(r1, 1.0 / *lead);

            #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
            for(int r2 = 0; r2 < h; r2++)
            {
                if(r2 == r1 || (*this)[r2][rank] == 0)
                    continue;
                if(mirror)
                    mirror->add_row(r2, r1, -(*this)[r2][rank]);
                add_row(r2, r1, -(*this)[r2][rank]);
            }
            clamp_zeros();
        }

        size_t zero_count = 0;
        for(size_t r = 0; r < h; r++)
        {
            double* lead = find_leading(r);
            if(lead)
            {
                size_t rank = lead - (*this)[r];
                swap_rows(rank, r);
                if(mirror)
                    mirror->swap_rows(rank, r);
            }
            else
            {
                size_t with = h - ++zero_count;
                swap_rows(r, with);
                if(mirror)
                    mirror->swap_rows(r, with);
            }
        }
    }

    private:

    double* data;
    size_t w, h;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Matrix& m)
{
    o << setprecision(2);
    for(size_t j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
    {
        o << "----------";
    }
    o << "--\n";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m.height(); i++)
    {
        o << "|";
        for(size_t j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
        {
            o << setw(10) << m[i][j];
        }
        o << "|\n";
    }
    for(size_t j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
    {
        o << "----------";
    }
    o << "--";
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    int iMaxThreads = omp_get_max_threads();
    omp_set_num_threads(iMaxThreads);

    omp_set_dynamic(false);
    omp_set_nested(true);

    srand(time(0));
    Matrix m (10000, 10000);

    for(int i = 0; i < m.height(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m.width(); j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    time_t start = time(0);
    m.row_reduce();
    time_t end = time(0);
    cout << m[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "dt = " << (end - start) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is strange.  I kind of expected that it may work on another platform.  I might try it on my laptop.  Right now I am compiling gcc 5.2.  I want to test it with cilkplus.  Thanks for running it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code on Linux 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu 64-bit using GCC 4.9.2.

As depicted below, it used some RAM, but I haven't crashed yet with 11 minutes of CPU time on the clock and RAM holding steady.

[image: System Stats]

Comment: Thanks for running it.  I really wonder what it is with my system that is causing it.  I am trying it right now with cilkplus and gcc 5.2.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: Just did the same thing with cilk.

Comment: Can you try a different version of GCC?

Comment: Perhaps your matrix's internal data is not being shared between the threads? Were that the case and you had a many-core processor you would end up making many copies of the matrix, which could result in your machine running out of memory. You could use `#pragma omp parallel for shared(data)` to test this.

Comment: I don't think so because when I monitor my memory in system monitor it stays at exactly the same value.  Also the matrix is allocated on the heap not the stack.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it isn't really a programming issue at all.  My program ran fine on my laptop and on other peoples systems apparently.  I just ran the y cruncher 2.5 billion digits of pi benchmark.  This cause my computer to crash in the exact same way.  After this I tried out the windows version of y cruncher.  It caused a blue screen after about 30 seconds.  I suppose it is a hardware issue which occurs after memory or cpu has been pushed really hard for a while.  Now I have my excuse to upgrade to a skylake cpu.

UPDATE:
I managed to fix it.  A while back I flicked on the EZ XMP switch on my asus motherboard.  This is meant to automatically over clock memory.  I had tried the cpu over clocking settings on my motherboard before and they always made my system unstable.  The memory however seemed to work so I left it on and forgot about it.  I guess this wasn't the case and it was causing my crash.  Now that I turned it off my both y cruncher and openmp can run to completion.

Comment: Your system is crashing for a reason. You should find out why. Did you overclock it? Is it overheating?

Comment: I tried resetting my bios.  I don't really bother with over clocking.  I posted a full description of the issue on a hardware forum if you are interested.  http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2827072/component-failing.html